# How can it be I can fetch my title, but not my exercise word from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

This is how my JSON looks like

```
{
"main_object": {
"id": "new",
"getExerciseTitle": "TestToConfirm",
"language": "nl_NL",
"application": "lettergrepen",
"main_object": {
  "title": "TestToConfirm",
  "language": "nl_NL",
  "exercises": [
    {
      "word": "huisarts",
      "syllables": [
        "huis",
        "arts"
      ]
    }
  ]
},
"dataType": "json"
  }
}
```

this is how I fetch `getExerciseTitle`:

```
var ID = getUrlParameter("id");
var MEDIAARRAY;
//console.log(ID);

$(document).ready(function () {

$.getJSON('json_files/jsonData_' + ID + '.json', function(json) {
 //console.log(json);


var exercisetitle = json.main_object.getExerciseTitle;
   $("#getExerciseTitle").html(exercisetitle);


createExercise(json);
    });

});
```

And this is how I am trying to fetch the `words` (but this doesn't work, and I am wondering how can this be?

```
function createExercise(json) {
var exWord = json.main_object.main_object.exercises.word;
     $.each(exWord, function(data, value) {
         console.log(exWord);
     });

}
```

My `console.log()` doesn't show any error and I have no idea what I am doing wrong since I am using the same method to fetch my `exercisetitle`.

Comment: your `exercises` is Array. Try to get via Index. or  `forEach`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exercises` is an *array*, not an object. You'll have to access the elements of the array in order to access the object(s) with the `word` property.

```
function createExercise(json) {
  const exercises = json.main_object.main_object.exercises;
  exercises.forEach(function(exercise) {
    console.log(exercise.word);
  });
}
```

Comment: Your answer is correct (so is mister T.J Crowder his), but I cannot check it as "correct answer" before 9 min. have gone by. so I'll give it a "correct answer" in 9 min, my apologies for the delay. can't help it. although we are on the topic anyway, would it also be possible to loop through the exercises and attach the syllables that are part of the word into one? or do I have to make a new loop for this?

Comment: To merge strings in an array into a single string you can use `join`, eg `exercise.syllables.join(' ')` if that's what you're looking for

Comment: I believe that's correct (my knowledge isn't that much so i'll keep it in my newbie language), to fetch the "word" with the syllables that are part of that word. But I think we're on one line and it's me being a newbie. so i'll check on the .join. Thank you very much for the time and effort put into this.

Answer (score 1):

Because `json.main_object.main_object.exercises` is an **array**, which has no `word` property. It has an object as its only entry, and that object has `word`, not the array:

```
var exWord = json.main_object.main_object.exercises[0].word;
// ------------------------------------------------^^^
```

or a loop:

```
json.main_object.main_object.exercises.forEach(function(exercise) {
    var exWord = exercise.word;
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var json = {
"main_object": {
"id": "new",
"getExerciseTitle": "TestToConfirm",
"language": "nl_NL",
"application": "lettergrepen",
"main_object": {
  "title": "TestToConfirm",
  "language": "nl_NL",
  "exercises": [
    {
      "word": "huisarts",
      "syllables": [
        "huis",
        "arts"
      ]
    }
  ]
},
"dataType": "json"
  }
}



$(document).ready(function () {

   var exercisetitle = json.main_object.getExerciseTitle;
   $("#getExerciseTitle").html(exercisetitle);
  
   var r = json.main_object.main_object.exercises;
  
   $.each(r,function(data,value){
    console.log(data,value.word)
   })


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='getExerciseTitle'></div>
```

Because you are trying to access the array element without letting the code know the index of the element.

Comment: What does the ajax call do if u don't mind me asking?

Comment: Update a web page without reloading the page, Request data from a server - after the page has loaded, Receive data from a server - after the page has loaded and Send data to a server - in the background

Comment: oke, so basically what it does when I use 2 computers (for example) and I insert something in the back-end, I don't need to refresh the front-end to see the change? the code certainly does look good, and it seems to be correct.